# Ansible json_query filter

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

So I have this output resulted from ansible (pinging some hosts using shell module:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [10.240.18.58]
ok: [10.240.18.57] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": true,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "ping -c1 -W1 \"10.240.18.20\"",
                "delta": "0:00:00.005339",
                "end": "2020-02-05 10:41:06.527708",
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "ping -c1 -W1 \"10.240.18.20\"",
                        "_uses_shell": true,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "stdin": null,
                        "warn": true
                    }
                },
                "item": "10.240.18.20",
                "rc": 0,
                "start": "2020-02-05 10:41:06.522369",
                "stderr": "",
                "stderr_lines": [],
                "stdout": "PING 10.240.18.20 (10.240.18.20) 56(84) bytes of data.\n64 bytes from 10.240.18.20: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.268 ms\n\n--- 10.240.18.20 ping statistics ---\n1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms\nrtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.268/0.268/0.268/0.000 ms",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "PING 10.240.18.20 (10.240.18.20) 56(84) bytes of data.",
                    "64 bytes from 10.240.18.20: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.268 ms",
                    "",
                    "--- 10.240.18.20 ping statistics ---",
                    "1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms",
                    "rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.268/0.268/0.268/0.000 ms"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": true,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "ping -c1 -W1 \"10.240.23.34\"",
                "delta": "0:00:00.006229",
                "end": "2020-02-05 10:41:09.889206",
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "ping -c1 -W1 \"10.240.23.34\"",
                        "_uses_shell": true,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "stdin": null,
                        "warn": true
                    }
                },
                "item": "10.240.23.34",
                "rc": 0,
                "start": "2020-02-05 10:41:09.882977",
                "stderr": "",
                "stderr_lines": [],
                "stdout": "PING 10.240.23.34 (10.240.23.34) 56(84) bytes of data.\n64 bytes from 10.240.23.34: icmp_req=1 ttl=63 time=1.33 ms\n\n--- 10.240.23.34 ping statistics ---\n1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms\nrtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.333/1.333/1.333/0.000 ms",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "PING 10.240.23.34 (10.240.23.34) 56(84) bytes of data.",
                    "64 bytes from 10.240.23.34: icmp_req=1 ttl=63 time=1.33 ms",
                    "",
                    "--- 10.240.23.34 ping statistics ---",
                    "1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms",
                    "rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.333/1.333/1.333/0.000 ms"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": true,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "ping -c1 -W1 \"10.240.23.35\"",
                "delta": "0:00:00.006403",
                "end": "2020-02-05 10:41:13.237920",
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "ping -c1 -W1 \"10.240.23.35\"",
                        "_uses_shell": true,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "stdin": null,
                        "warn": true
                    }
                },
                "item": "10.240.23.35",
                "rc": 0,
                "start": "2020-02-05 10:41:13.231517",
                "stderr": "",
                "stderr_lines": [],
                "stdout": "PING 10.240.23.35 (10.240.23.35) 56(84) bytes of data.\n64 bytes from 10.240.23.35: icmp_req=1 ttl=63 time=1.36 ms\n\n--- 10.240.23.35 ping statistics ---\n1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms\nrtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.364/1.364/1.364/0.000 ms",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "PING 10.240.23.35 (10.240.23.35) 56(84) bytes of data.",
                    "64 bytes from 10.240.23.35: icmp_req=1 ttl=63 time=1.36 ms",
                    "",
                    "--- 10.240.23.35 ping statistics ---",
                    "1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms",
                    "rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.364/1.364/1.364/0.000 ms"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I've created an ansible task and I want to display using debug strictly these lines:

```
 "stdout_lines": [
                    "PING 10.240.18.20 (10.240.18.20) 56(84) bytes of data.",
                    "64 bytes from 10.240.18.20: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.268 ms",
```

for each of the hosts.

The ansible task would be this:

```
   - debug:
       msg: "{{ smm_ping.json | json_query(pfilter) }}"
     vars:
       pfilter: "[*].{Ping response: stdout_lines}"
     when: "('primary' in default_hostname or 'Primary' in default_hostname)"
     tags: ['ic', 'smm']
```

For some reason it's not working:

```
TASK [debug]
fatal: [10.240.18.57]: FAILED! => {"msg": "JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:\nExpecting: colon, got: unquoted_identifier: Parse error at column 10, token \"response\" (UNQUOTED_IDENTIFIER), for expression:\n\"[*].{Ping response: stdout_lines}\"\n           ^"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your identifier has a space in it, you need to quote it.

`pfilter: "[*].{\"Ping response\": stdout_lines}"`

To ease the writing/readability, you can use a yaml folded block scalar and remove one level of quote escaping:

```
pfilter: >-
  [*].{"Ping response": stdout_lines}
```

Note: The quoting character for jmespath identifiers is the double quote (`"`). **Don't use single quotes** which are used for string values. See jmespath specification below.

Refs:

- http://jmespath.org/specification.html#identifiers
- http://yaml-multiline.info/

Comment: Any ideea how do I filter the stdout_lines output to only show `64 bytes from 10.240.18.20: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.268 ms` and ignore all the other lines?

Comment: Hint. `stdout_lines` is a list. The element you are looking for is always the second one. List index starts at 0.

Comment: Apparently this is not working anymore in ansible 2.9.x. Any clues?

Comment: "not working" is not an accurate description of your problem. And in this case, the ansible version is probably not the issue. For what it's worth, I play roles using `json_query` daily with ansible 2.9.x without any issues. If this is a fresh ansible install, did you `pip install jmespath` ?

Comment: No, I didn't :)) That was the issue, the output was not fully filtered, thanks! that pip install did the trick!